# how to run a single test on multiple machines using selenium grid, i am using maven and test ng

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid2

```
I have a testng.xml like this :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite verbose="0" name="Selenium Parallel Aim Suite" parallel="tests" >
  <test name="FB login and Screen capture" parallel="true">

    <classes>

    <class name="com.jm.webdriver.JTest1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
    <test name="Google Search" parallel="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="com.jm.webdriver.JTest2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I want to launch these two test cases on say three machines 1. Windows, 2 linux 3. Mac parallelly, How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be parallel = "true" for suite tag and parallel property is not required for test tags. If you are looking for grid setup then refer the seleniumhq.org documentation.

Comment: Thanks but i would need more clarity on how to setup it for running on three machines as in parallely , any external links will be helpful.